# Is it possible to submit a form and return to another page using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a form from another website. It is "post method". Its a free SMS service. So i was wondering if i can use the form to submit data and return to another page on my website. I don't know even if its possible. I don't know much about javascript. Please help

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could use `ajax`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
but I doubt it would work because they probably look what server makes the request.

Answer (score 0):

after the submission condition feeds succesfully
try

```
window.location.href=www.google.com/type the url you want to go
```